# Regex get html input value dynamic tag position

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I've question about how to get value from input html when the tag position is dynamic.
This is the example input:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" value="fname.lname@gmail.com" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled">

<input type="text" autocomplete="" value="fname.lname@gmail.com" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled">
```

This is what I'm able to do, but can not detect if tag value position before id position like in the second example.

```
/<input(?:.*?)id=\"emailaddress\"(?:.*)value=\"([^"]+).*>/i
```

Comment: Can you show the sample code?

Comment: Wait I got problem posting by mobile phone. Switch to notebook.

Comment: Done @WilliamFeirie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<input.*?(?:id=\"emailaddress\".*?value=\"([^"]+)|value=\"([^"]+).*?id=\"emailaddress\")[^>]*>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Bryqs/3)

The matches are shown on the right pane (not visible on test string for some reason). Since there's a `|`, you'll have to check both group 1 and group 2.

As many pointed out though, this is not something that should be done with regular expressions if you can avoid it.

Comment: I think its is possibly correct. I'll try it when I'm home. Thanks.

Comment: Could you hepl me to answer my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097660/how-to-get-only-specific-input-html-tag-with-regex-that-separate-by-space, @Jeto?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Beautiful Soup" module.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<input type="text" autocomplete="" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" value="fname.lname@gmail.com" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="" value="fname.lname@gmail.com" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled">'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
print(soup.find(id="emailaddress")['value'])
```

In front end app,can you use jquery.js?

```
$("#emailaddress").val()

document.getElementById('emailaddress').value
```

Comment: Nope. I'm only able to use regex. No HTML parser because I'll do it in front end apps.

Comment: Can you use jquery.js?

Comment: Nope. No document, DOM, and any other front end standards enabled because it used based on jscore which is it doesn't have all that oustanding fearure.

Comment: You really should not be using regex to parse HTML, or else [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3483203)

Comment: You tagged your question with `preg_match`, a PHP function. Why then? @ChristoforusSurjoputro

Comment: @chrisz, not every case able to use HTML parser.