# How to get only specific <input> HTML tag with regex that separate by SPACE

Tags: regex, match

I've ask how to handle inconsistent HTML  tag attribute position here: [Regex get html input value dynamic tag position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092484/regex-get-html-input-value-dynamic-tag-position). I want to ask another question how to match only specific  that the string separate by SPACE, not by break line. This is the string example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" value="fname.lname@gmail.com" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled"> <input type="text" autocomplete="" value="joko145" name="confirmedUsername" id="username" maxlength="60" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled">
```

I've tried this:

```
<input.*?(?:id=\"username\".*?value=\"([^"]+)|value=\"([^"]+).*?id=\"username\")[^>]*>
```

to get the value, but instead it return the username value, it return emailaddress value. The first return array (full text detected by regex) like this:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="" name="confirmedEmailAddress" id="emailaddress" maxlength="60" value="fname.lname@gmail.com" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled"> <input type="text" autocomplete="" value="joko145" name="confirmedUsername" id="username" maxlength="60" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled">
```

It detect all the  from the string, not specific  that I want like below:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="" value="joko145" name="confirmedUsername" id="username" maxlength="60" class="txt-box  txtbox-m "  aria-describedby="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled">
```

It happened only when  HTML tag separate by SPACE, not by break line. How to get only the username when it separate by SPACE? Thanks.

Comment: What about https://regex101.com/r/d3ueaN/1?

Comment: That's the correct answer if you're using php. When I change the mode to javascript "Group1" which is the value, did not available. I also have tried it in my local apps, the value did not available. Any other solution, @revo?

Comment: It works in JS too. You can have access to first capturing group by `$1` https://regexr.com/3lm6n

Comment: I think it is not a good solution, because it is non standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n. Any other suggestion @revo?

Comment: Indeed, that reference is about the `$n` properties of the `RegExp` object, not the `$n` back-references. The latter is used without reservation in the [Regular Expressions topic on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You may get value the same way you did in your other question. There is no difference.